# Is there a way to add an unprotected range with the google sheets api?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I see in the documentation that you can add protected ranges and remove those that you add. But is there a way to add an unprotected range?

I need to unprotect 3 cells in a protected sheet and not seeing any ways to do so.

If I use the get api, I can see in the response there is a protected range for said sheet, with an array of unprotected ranges. Is there a request to add to that array of unprotected ranges?

The documentation has no leads.

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `a request to add to that array of unprotected ranges`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hey @Tanaike. Thank you for your reply. I have found a solution. I will comment as soon as I get a chance!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.